# Troubles in Raring Ringtail

Tags: 13.04

I upgrade ubuntu 12.10 to ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, in 12.10 Skype, Pidgin and Compiz Fusion Icon works pretty good, but with Raring Ringtal, I cant open skype and put Compiz Fusion Icon in the status bar, both don't works,  Pidgin don't show my contacts, I have uninstalled with synaptic remove all, and installed again with software center, but the problem cant be corrected.

In software and updates Ubuntu Raring Ringtail disable PPA check-boxes appears this message in parenthesis (disabled in the update to Raring) I cant activate the box

[image] again
What can I do?
Thank you in advance for the correct solution